# Ordering a dictionary by the spelling of a word - Python 3

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm, ordereddictionary

I was wondering if anyone knew a way to make a dictionary ordered by the spelling of a particular word? Since a dictionary is unsorted, I resorted to the use of OrderedDict, but I believe you can only sort it through the keys and values. Any idea of how to order it in this way?

Here's part of the project I was working on:

```
word = input("word")
list_1 = list(word)

word>? apple

len_list_1 = len(list_1)


dict = {}

for x in range(0, len(list_1)):
    dict[list_1[x]] = list_1.count(list_1[x])

print(dict)

>{'l': 1, 'p': 2, 'a': 1, 'e': 1}
```

I was trying to keep it in order of the word 'apple' and then somehow convert the dictionary into plain text:

```
{'a' : 1, 'p': 2, 'l': 1, 'e': 1}
> a1p2l1e1 #as my final answer
```

Comment: Just to clarify you want it ordered by the the "first seen" order in a word? So `mississippi` would yield `{'m': 1, 'i': 4, 's':4, 'p': 2}` / `m1i4s4p4` ?

Comment: @AndrewGelnar Yes, that's exactly the way I need it to be.

Answer (score 3):

As a first point, note that your code is a pretty inefficient and unpythonic way of doing something pretty simple:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('apple')
Counter({'p': 2, 'a': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 1})
```

(Inefficient, because you are counting every letter every time, e.g. 'aaaaa' will count 'a' 5 times; unpythonic, because you declare and don't use a length variable and loop throw with `range(len(...))` which is almost never a good idea.)

You can then sort this counter and make it an `OrderedDict`. I am sorting by the first occurrence in the word:

```
>>> word = 'apple'
>>> c = Counter(word)
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(c.items(), key=lambda x: word.index(x[0])))
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('p', 2), ('l', 1), ('e', 1)])
```

Note that the answer will be very different if you are simply grouping letters: a dictionary is not the right data structure if you want to do something like `'b1o1b1'`.

If your desired output is just the string `'a1p2l1e1'`, you can do the following:

```
>>> word = 'apple'
>>> c = Counter(word)
>>> sorted_letter_counts = sorted(c.items(), key=lambda x: word.index(x[0]))
>>> ''.join(c + str(n) for c,n in sorted_letter_counts)
'a1p2l1e1'
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
>>> word = 'apple'
>>> ''.join(c + str(n) for c,n in sorted(Counter('apple').items(), key=lambda x: word.index(x[0])))
'a1p2l1e1'
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I've learned so much by your example. I'm new to Python and still trying to figure out what is Pythonic and what isn't.

Answer (score 0):

[Straight from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes):

```
class OrderedCounter(collections.Counter, collections.OrderedDict):
    'Counter that remembers the order elements are first encountered'

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, collections.OrderedDict(self))

    def __reduce__(self):
        '''__reduce__ is for pickling'''
        return self.__class__, (collections.OrderedDict(self),)
```

Usage:

```
>>> foo = OrderedCounter('apple')
>>> foo
OrderedCounter(OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('p', 2), ('l', 1), ('e', 1)]))
>>>

>>> for thing in foo.items():
    print(thing)


('a', 1)
('p', 2)
('l', 1)
('e', 1)
>>>
```